# Should I use a WiFi router or an access point in my home network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, internet-connection, dsl-modem

My internet connection becomes disturbed all the time especially when in work hours. I tried to diagnose the problem and I came across several reasons happening together.
I have a VDSL modem router with WiFi capability.

Both my ISP and my line actually have problems but I've found out that my modem itself is failing from time to time, resulting in request time outs when pinging it. So I thought it might be overloaded under the amount of job it's handling.

We have quite a lot of devices at home. We are four people, each having their own phone and laptop and we have extra phones and a desktop computer too.

So I thought I'd better separate the concern of handling wireless network and those requests from the modem and transfer those responsibilities to another devices. Now I'm wondering if I should use a router or an access point.

I have an old D-Link router and I have set it up on a different SSID and connected it to the modem. It works but sometimes it also gets unresponsive. I recall I had some issues with this device in the past when I used to use it with a simple ADSL modem. But I'm not really sure if I'm doing anything wrong or it's the devices fault.

I'm considering buying a new device but I want to choose the right kind.

I'm also unsure whether I should keep the modem responsible for DHCP, routing and stuff. I also don't know about small details I should be considering. I might be some kind of a geek but I'm just a software developer not a network engineer. So I'm just doing trial and error.

Another totally different approach might be changing the whole modem device with a new one with higher capacity. Sometimes I feel like the modem is out of memory or something! Then I turn it off and on again it starts responding!

So, any piece of advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears that you may have more devices and people than your ISP plan supports. You should determine what plan you need before you add devices to split up a plan that does not cover your needs.

Comment: @john, this user is having IW problems from what it sounds like. The speed under his plan doesn't matter if he is having SNR issues on the VDSL. These issues should be delt with first...

Comment: Can you provide screenshots from the modems diagnostic page? Specifically the signal to noise readings from the modem?

Comment: @John the situation I'm describing here wasn't the case right after we got this service. Everything was fine at first. Even now, internet speed is mostly good at night. My modem signal sometimes drops suddenly. Sometime my ping requests to the modem itself time out! I'm pinging the local interface at 192.168.1.1

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I'll try. I haven't gotten used to its administrative panel yet. I previously had D-Link devices. This one isn't from a well-known brand but was provided by the ISP. I don't know where to read reports about noises

Comment: I would start with the basics - put the device on ethernet, and troubleshoot with the simplest setup possible (e.g. remove splitters, replace network cables, reseat connections, etc).  ISP connection drops will not produce an internal network outage as you appear to be having.  You should be able to ping the router at all times. The ISP can easily tell if SNR / signal problems are a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check your internet cables and the sub- internet booth. Maybe the problem comes from there. Maybe there're some overflow on the board you're connecting from. Try to check these things before you get the step forward to buy a router or access point. **Router** is suitable for you. **Access point** for Home purposes not that recommend.

**Check** your external connection and figure out where the problem comes from. Your unstable connection maybe comes from the booth you connect to or your ex-cables. Six years without maintenance on the network it really **Too much**. Get in-touch with your provided company and ask them to send you a technical support.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by sub-internet booth. I have external problems for sure. But my primary concern here is about the internal problems. As I said, the modem itself sometimes doesn't respond to pings.

Comment: You're not connecting with main booth by sure. In every district there're small booths that feed local areas and there's main booth for each district. What I concern is having an overflow on your small booth. So, the ip which you're receiving is unstable.